# ReferenceError: document is not defined in React app using document.addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, dom, addeventlistener, referenceerror

I am making a React app and I am trying to use the browser api to detect if a user is on the app tab or another one.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
  if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('user is not in this tab')
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Is this because I am calling document from a React app?

Comment: What do you mean by a React app? React can be used for server-side rendering, where you don't have a document. Otherwise, everything is available as in plain javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the component is rendered.
Therefore you should use the useEffect Hook